# How to specify an exception breakpoint for specific exception class on VScode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

How to specify exception breakpoints for specific exception classes on VScode?

VSCode UI supports "trap all Exception" option in the "Run and Debug" pane.
However I can't find out how to specify exception classes.

[Official page for Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/) seems support filtering option on [SetExceptionBreakpoints](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_SetExceptionBreakpoints), but I can't find out how to specify a filtering option on VSCode UI.